# Populate SQLite data onto UWP App

Tags: c#, xaml, sqlite, uwp

I want to populate SQLite data onto my App.

Lets say I have created an app to record details about football matches going on.
I have 3 TextBox( teamName, goalScored, goalConceded) and a Button to Insert these values onto the DataBase.
Also lets say that I have inserted details onto db.

What I want is to populate these data/details from database onto a ListView(defined in XAML) in my app.

Comment: You need to be more specific with your problem and show examples of what you have tried so far.  Generally SO won't respond well to questions so broad.  Please post code across all languages and processes that you have implemented so far.

Comment: What have you tried so far to retrieve the data from DB and show it on your UI? Please read [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your ListView to a ViewModel property (usually ObservableCollection).
Then after insert just update ObservableCollection data.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is to populate these data/details from database onto a ListView(defined in XAML) in my app.

Firstly you need to query the data from the database according to your requirements. For how to get the data depended on the SQLite Nuget package you are using for the UWP app. Secondly you may need to read the data to a source collection, may be [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms668604(v=vs.105).aspx) as @Ion Caisîn said. Here the best practice is to have entities, build models for table data. At last bind the source to the [`ListView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview).

Following is a simple demo about reading the data from a SQLite database and bind data to `ListView`. I'm using the [SQLitePCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCL/) Nuget package.

XAML code:

```
<Button x:Name="btngetdata" Content="get data" Click="btngetdata_Click"></Button>
<ListView x:Name="ListCustomer" SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Margin="2,10,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="2,10,0,0" Text="{Binding City}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="2,10,0,0" Text="{Binding Contact}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{ 
   ...
    private void btngetdata_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListCustomer.ItemsSource = SQLiteHelp.getValues();
    }
}

public class SQLiteHelp
{
    private static string DbName = "Sun.db";       
    public static ObservableCollection<Customer> getValues()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Customer> list = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(DbName))
        {
            using (var statement = connection.Prepare(@"SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER;"))
            {
                while (statement.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
                {
                    list.Add(new Customer()
                    {
                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(statement[0]),
                        Name = (string)statement[1],
                        City = (string)statement[2],
                        Contact = statement[3].ToString()
                    });

                    Debug.WriteLine(statement[0] + " ---" + statement[1] + " ---" + statement[2] + statement[3]);
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

}
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
}
```

More details please reference [this guide](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/A-Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10/10) which is for SQLite local database in UWP. And there is a [SQLite in UWP app sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/windows-developer-blog-samples/tree/master/Samples/SQLiteSample) which use [Microsoft.Data.SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SQLite/) package you may also reference.